# GLM on police stops data in Gelman / Hill book

Tags: r, statistics

Has anyone worked with NY police stops data mentioned in Gelman, Hill book *Data Analysis Using Reg. and Multi/Hier Modeling* (ARM). The data is under

http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/examples/police/

the file is frisk_with_noise.dat. I removed the description part of this data, renamed past.arrests as arrests, saved it as frisk.dat. Called glm from R like this:

```
library ("foreign")
frisk <- read.table ("frisk.dat", header=TRUE)
attach (frisk)
glm(formula = stops ~ 1, family=poisson, offset=log(arrests))
```

The glm call is right out of ARM book. In any case, I get the error:

```
Error: NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 4)
```

Any ideas? Gelman has a piece of code under the same directory called police_setup.R that is supposed to have some cleanup code, but that doesnt work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't gone back to look at exactly what Gelman is doing in this chapter (my copy of the book is in storage ...), but the specific problem with this example is that 'arrests' is zero in some cases, so using log(arrests) as an offset causes problems. (You don't need library(foreign), and using a data argument to glm is usually safer/better than using attach().)

```
X <- read.table("frisk_with_noise.dat",skip=6,header=TRUE)
names(X)[3] <- "arrests"
glm(stops~1,family=poisson,offset=log(arrests),data=X,
    subset=arrests>0)
```

Comment: I ran it like you show, it says
(Intercept)  
    -0.5877  

Degrees of Freedom: 898 Total (i.e. Null);  898 Residual
Null Deviance:     184000 
Residual Deviance: 184000  AIC: 189300 
> 

Book has (Intercept)      -3.4    0.0
  n = 225, k = 1
  residual deviance = 44877, null deviance = 44877 (difference = 0)

This is an improvement tho, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The above code works, but the analysis results are different from the book. According to [this blogpost](http://ascratchpad.blogspot.nl/2010/09/arm-62.html) the authors had to manually change the data because of privacy concerns.

Answer (score 1):

For Gelman's chapter 6 example, I believe you first need to aggregate over crime. The frisk_with_noise.dat file contains 900 observations, one record per ethnic group, per precinct, *per crime* (75 * 3 * 4 = 900). But the example output in chapter 6 shows n = 225 (75 * 3). So expanding on Ben's code with something like this gets you a little closer to replicating the output:

```
library(arm) # for display() function
X <- read.table("frisk_with_noise.dat",skip=6,header=TRUE)
names(X)[3] <- "arrests"
X <- aggregate(cbind(stops, arrests) ~ precinct + eth, data=X, sum)
fit.1 <- glm(stops~1,family=poisson,offset=log(arrests),data=X,
             subset=arrests>0)
display(fit.1)
```

But as the note at the top of the frisk_with_noise.dat file points out, noise has been added so the results can't be replicated exactly.